# Turning off specific javascript function for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding turning off javascript for mobile users so that it specifically stops using a parallax scrolling feature called "stellar". I had it working but somewhere along the way of designing my site it stopped functioning and I can't figure out why. I have two basic parts (shown below):

```
//check for mobile
    window.mobilecheck = function() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
        return check; 
    }

//run check for mobile  
    if(!window.mobilecheck()){
        //parallax scrolling
        $(function(){
            $.stellar({
                horizontalScrolling: false,
                verticalOffset: 0
            });
        });
    }
```

Any thoughts? (sorry for the code block long text)

Comment: It depends on how you define "mobile". What does "my site it stopped functioning" mean? Is the server turned on?

Comment: If all of this is wrapped in a document ready somewhere then the `$(function(){` that is around `$.stellar` could be the problem. Also `window.mobilecheck` doesn't need to be a function, it could just be an anonymous function like you already have inside of it: `window.mobilecheck = (function (a) {return AllTheRegex;})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);`

Comment: Yes, it's all inside a $(document).ready

Comment: What is the exact problem, is it running `$.stellar` always? Like no matter if it is mobile. Or is it not running it at all?

Comment: $.stellar is running all the time regardless. Previously it was working only on desktop as intended, I'm honestly not sure what changed

Comment: I ran a test to pop up an alert to see whether "var check" was changing true false for mobile vs desktop and it is so hopefully that helps in diagnosing

Comment: Are you sure your criteria is "one of this list of known ua strings" as opposed to "has only touchscreen input"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually turned out to be with the CSS background-attachment property. It needed to be fixed for the $stellar parallax scrolling effect to work, but change to scroll when $stellar was not activated. So in addition to what I had above I amended the last part as follows:

```
//Run check for mobile  
if(!window.mobilecheck())
{
    //parallax scrolling for NOT mobile
    $.stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalOffset: 0
    });
}
    //All background images scroll with element for MOBILE ONLY
else {
    $('#home').css({'background-attachment':"scroll"});
    $('.blockHeader').css({'background-attachment':"scroll"});
}
```